# "Expression has changed after it was checked" when child component emits on ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which displays a list of validation errors and renders a list of child components with `ngFor`. Each child component performs its validation during `ngOnInit` and outputs the result to the parent component. The parent component listens for this output and updates the list of validation errors, the result of which throws an error:

`Expression has changed after it was checked`

Now, I understand why this error is being thrown - at the start of the change detection cycle the validation errors were in one state, and at the end it was in another state, and this is not allowed.

What I do not understand is how to get around this issue. The parent component has to display a list of errors at the top of the page, and each child component will add their validation results to this list. If this is a breach of the uni-directional dataflow then please tell me how to get around this in a clean manner (i.e, not wrapping the validation in a `setTimeout`, not changing from an immutable list to a mutable one, and not explicitly invoking the change detector again after validation).

Plunker reproducing the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/q52A1DraNOnxZa0qGFDo?p=preview

---

**EDIT**

I've "solved" the issue by constructing the `EventEmitter` with the `isAsync` flag:

`new EventEmitter(true)`

This means that values will be emitted asynchronously, so emitted values will be picked up on the *next* change detection cycle. I guess the result is the same as wrapping the logic in a `setTimeout` but this way at least we don't have to wrap our code in a timeout everywhere we may emit a value.

Comment: thank you for your soultion.

Comment: Thanks for the async solution!

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't like when change detection itself causes changes and `ngOnInit` is called by change detection.

In devMode change detection does an additional change detection run after each regular change detection run, to check if the model is stable. 
If the model changed during change detection, it throws this error.

You can delay the change until after change detection is completed using

```ts
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.output.emit({value: true});
    }
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7P9PwA3OmGR3GUarHvij?p=preview)

**Update (see Ghetolay's comment below)**

> `ngOnInit` is not called by change detection and you can do bind changes inside it. What you cannot do is making change on a parent from a child's `ngOnInit` cause this breaks unidirectional data flow.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10131#issuecomment-233369491

Comment: Imagine I'm writing a component for a 3rd party, which upon initialisation needs to output some data, and I don't know how this component will be integrated. Unless I, for no intuitive reason whatsoever, wrap this initialisation logic within a `setTimeout`, the app integrating my component will throw this error and fixing it is out of their control. I'm either A) missing how I should be outputting values from child components correctly, or B) because of a limitation of the change detector need to add `setTimeouts` everywhere to stop the change detector from erroring.

Comment: I think the additional change detection cycle is unavoidable. Angular is in the middle of runnimg change detection when that change happens. Therefore another change detection cycle is necessary for the unified dataflow to work.

Comment: My main concern is the integration, not the additional CD cycle, which my comment didn't mention. How do I know when I need to wrap my logic in a `setTimeout`? How do I explain to my colleagues that in order to prevent change detection issues they should wrap all their initialisation logic in a `setTimeout`, *just in case*?

Comment: It's not every initialization logic. If you do it in the constructor, you don't need `setTimeout`, if the model change is done in an event handler or `subscribe` or `then` callback then it's just fine. If you only modify the state of the current component instance, you can use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` (which us local to the component and synchronous), only if you emit an event or modify the status of a shared service that potentially causes changes in a parent component as part of the change detection run, `setTimeout` is required. Rhis is usually rather rare.

Comment: Are you still missing something.

Comment: Could you recommend what the best architectural approach for this solution would be? If i need to add timeouts then I can't be following what Angular intended. Would it be the parent component using something like `ViewChildren` and implementing `ngOnChanges` to react to changes in the child components? Would it be using a service? Using observables in some way? If so what would that architecture look like? This probably makes for a separate question but a high level response would be helpful.

Comment: What's the problem with 'setTimeout` for this specific case?

Comment: Injecting timeouts into code to duck errors seems like a really bad practice. There has to be a better way.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith see my comment above about `detectChanges`

Comment: My situation is this - I have a parent component that displays nav and the page title, then loads child components into a router outlet based on what's clicked in the nav. The child component updates a page title service with its page name, and the parent component subscribes to that service to get and display the page title. Since 4.1.x, that's created the error. It seems like a simple and normal pattern to me, and wrapping all the setTitle calls in my child components with a timeout to duck this error feels wrong.

Comment: You get the error when you change the model in a callback called from change detection. Can you reproducevin a Plunker?

Comment: `ngOnInit` is not called by change detection and you can do bind changes inside it. What you cannot do is making change on a parent from a child's `ngOnInit` cause this breaks unidirectional data flow.

Comment: @Ghetolay you are right. Thanks for the update. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10131#issuecomment-233369491

Comment: I faced this issue when changing the property value of a service class and moving the initialisation into the constructor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to change anything in `ngOnInit`. Angular 2 team refused to consider this as a bug ([#10131](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10131)), so yes, you have to do it in unclean way: `setTimeout(..., 0)` or `Promise.resolve().then(...)`.

Comment: Not sure I follow with "not being able to change anything in `ngOnInit`".. what's its purpose then? My understanding is that `ngOnInit` is essentially used for setting up data/subscriptions instead of the constructor for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, idea is to start fetching data in `ngOnInit`, also doing this in constructor is considered bad for testing, however in real life you will need to setup component fields in response to input properties values and there is no right place for this action, the only way is to use delays.

Comment: Same as gunter answer about `ngOnInit` see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the child component like always, but in the parent component i did like this (trigger change detection only if the incoming value is different):

```
  getStatus(status: StatusModel) {
    if (this.currentStatus !== status) {
      this.currentStatus = status;
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```